# Secure FTP for Windows 2000 Server

Tags: windows, ftp, security, windows-server-2000, ftps

Can someone recommend a secure FTP implementation that works well on Windows Server 2000? I'm uploading files into virtual directories and web applications under IIS and the existing provider, obviously, isn't secure or encrypted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try filezilla server? http://filezilla-project.org/

It supports FTP over SSL/TLS

Check out -
http://wiki.filezilla-project.org/FileZilla_FTP_Server

Comment: From that very page: Support for SFTP (SSH File Transfer Protocol) is not implemented in Filezilla Server.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.serv-u.com/

Is good. They support both ftp/ssl and Sftp.

Answer (score 0):

This solution cost money; nonetheless, we've recommended it to some clients before as it's pretty simple to setup. http://www.serv-u.com/

Answer (score 0):

[Free SSHD](http://www.freesshd.com/) works well. It supports remote console as well as file transfer, plus secure port forwarding.

Answer (score 0):

[CrossFTP Server](http://www.crossftp.com/), free and provides FTP/TLS support as a secure FTP server.

Answer (score 0):

Try [CompleteFTP](http://www.enterprisedt.com/products/completeftp/overview.html). It's a fast, compact, easy to install Windows server that supports SFTP and FTPS.

And you don't need to purchase the most expensive edition to get SFTP support - for $199 you get FTP, FTPS and SFTP.